# How to process an array of task asynchronously with swift combine

Tags: swift, combine

I have a publisher which takes a network call and returns an array of IDs. I now need to call another network call for each ID to get all my data. And I want the final publisher to have the resulting object.

First network result:

```
"user": {
   "id": 0,
   "items": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Final object:

```
struct User {
    let id: Int
    let items: [Item]
    ... other fields ...
}
struct Item {
    let id: Int
    ... other fields ...
}
```

Handling multiple network calls:

```
userPublisher.flatMap { user in
    let itemIDs = user.items
    return Future<[Item], Never>() { fulfill in
        ... OperationQueue of network requests ...
    }
}
```

I would like to perform the network requests in parallel, since they are not dependent on each other. I'm not sure if Future is right here, but I'd imagine I would then have code to do a
DispatchGroup or OperationQueue and fulfill when they're all done. Is there more of a Combine way of doing this?

Doe Combine have a concept of splitting one stream into many parallel streams and joining the streams together?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Combine offers extensions around `URLSession` to handle network requests unless you really need to integrate with `OperationQueue` based networking, then `Future` is a fine candidate. You can run multiple `Future`s and collect them at some point, but I'd really suggest looking at `URLSession` extensions for Combine.

```
struct User: Codable {
   var username: String
}

let requestURL = URL(string: "https://example.com/")!
let publisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: requestURL)
    .map { $0.data }
    .decode(type: User.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

Regarding running a batch of requests, it's possible to use `Publishers.MergeMany`, i.e:

```
struct User: Codable {
   var username: String
}

let userIds = [1, 2, 3]

let subscriber = Just(userIds)
    .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
    .flatMap { (values) -> Publishers.MergeMany<AnyPublisher<User, Error>> in
    let tasks = values.map { (userId) -> AnyPublisher<User, Error> in
            let requestURL = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/\(userId)")!

            return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: requestURL)
                .map { $0.data }
                .decode(type: User.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    return Publishers.MergeMany(tasks)
}.collect().sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
    if case .failure(let error) = completion {
        print("Got error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}) { (allUsers) in
    print("Got users:")
    allUsers.map { print("\($0)") }
}
```

In the example above I use `collect` to collect all results, which postpones emitting the value to the `Sink` until all of the network requests successfully finished, however you can get rid of the `collect` and receive each `User` in the example above one by one as network requests complete.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. There's no description on MergeMany :( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/mergemany

Comment: When merging many requests, I want to keep a time delay for each request. How can I do that?

Comment: @Surya add `.delay(..)`