# Swift Combine: collect after sequence publisher not called

Tags: swift, combine

I have a subject which sends/receives an array of Data like `PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()`. When a value is received I want to split the array in single values to manipulate them and afterwards collect them again.

I know that the issue is that the `flatMap` never sends the completion Event. But how can I solves this issue? Or is there a better way to manipulate every value in an array with combine?

Edit:
I don‘t want to complete the subject to collect. I want to collect the output of the sequencer.

Example:

```
import Combine

var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let subject = PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()

subject
    .flatMap { $0.publisher }
    .map { $0 * 10 }
    .collect()
    .sink {
        print($0) // Never called
    }
    .store(in: &storage)

subject.send([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

`collect` waits for the publisher to complete. A `PassthroughSubject` doesn't automatically complete. You need to call `send(completion:` on it.

```
subject.send([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
subject.send(completion: .finished) // now `sink` will be triggered
```

Comment: But what can I do if I don‘t want to complete the subject?

Comment: @Noroxs don't use `collect`. The whole point of `collect` is to wait for the publisher to complete and only then emit the values, since it collects _all_ values and it can only know that _all_ values were emitted once the publisher completes. You could also use `collect(5)` to emit every time 5 values were published.

Comment: Careful if you send complete: .finished the sink will also no longer get values

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `flatMap()` and the `collect()` calls, you can simply `map()` over the received array:

```swift
subject
    .map { $0.map { $0 * 10 } }
    .sink {
        print($0) // Now it's called :)
    }
    .store(in: &storage)

subject.send([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer helped me to find the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution how I achieved the my expected outcome. I had to move the `map` and `collect` within the `flatMap`.

```
import Combine

var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let subject = PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()

subject
    .flatMap { $0.publisher
        .map { $0 * 10 }
        .collect()
    }
    .sink {
        print($0)
    }
    .store(in: &storage)

subject.send([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
subject.send([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reversed())
```

This will print `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` and `[50, 40, 30, 20, 10]`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841254/combine-framework-how-to-process-each-element-of-array-asynchronously-before-pr for the case where the processing you are doing in `.map` is itself asynchronous.