# Swift Combine Sink Array AnyPublisher

Tags: swift, combine

I would like to wait for data from all elements and combine them into one result:

```
Item: AnyPublisher <Int, Swift.Error>
Array: AnyPublisher <[Result<Int, Swift.Error>], Never>
```

Can this be done somehow? I've tried using Zip and Merge - but I couldn't get the desired result.

Example:

```
func createItem(num: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Swift.Error> {
    Just(num)
        .setFailureType(to: Swift.Error.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
func createItems(nums: [Int]) -> AnyPublisher<[Result<Int, Swift.Error>], Never> {
    Publishers.MergeMany(nums.map { self.createItem(num: $0) } )
        .collect()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Function but "createItems" does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841254/combine-framework-how-to-process-each-element-of-array-asynchronously-before-pr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to generate an array of results - whether a value or an error - emitted by each publisher for each array value.

`MergeMany` + `Collect` is the right approach here. `MergeMany` will complete only when all its input publishers complete, and `.collect()` will for for that completion event before emitting.

Using your example:

```
func createItems(nums: [Int]) -> AnyPublisher<[Result<Int, Error>], Never> {

    let publishers = nums.map { v -> AnyPublisher<Result<Int, Error>, Never> in
        createItem(num: v) // AnyPublisher<Int, Error>
           .first() // ensure a single result
           .map { .success($0) } // map value to .success result
           .catch { Just(.failure($0)) } // map error to .failure result
           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    return Publishers.MergeMany(publishers)
        .collect() // wait for MergeMany to complete
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is something else to do after collect? i added an example.

Comment: @ОлегПривалов, so, you want an array of results - whether value or error - from each publisher? What happens if there are multiple values emitted by each of the publisher?

Comment: i plan to get one value from each publisher and unsubscribe

Comment: there will be publishers at the entrance sending the result once (request to the server).

Comment: Thank you very much!