# Swift Combine transform an array of publishers

Tags: swift, combine

I'm getting my way through Combine bit I don't seem to wrap my head around some trivial operations. I'm building a Combine based to do some HealthKit operations. Mainly I have two operations:

1. `func workouts(_ limit: Int) -> AnyPublisher<[HKWorkout], Error>`
2. `func workoutDetails(_ workout: HKWorkout) -> AnyPublisher<WorkoutDetails, Error>`

First off I will use the first one to query some workouts, that's easy.

```swift
HKHealthStore().workouts(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { subject in
        switch subject {
        
        case .finished:
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            dump(error)
        }
    }, receiveValue: { workouts in
        dump(workouts)
        // What now? 
    }).store(in: &bag)
```

Now I'd like to query the second function. It takes a workout as an argument and returns more information about the `HKWorkout`. How can I query the second function with the returned `[HKWorkout]` but don't know how to approach this.

- Should I do the query in a nested way in the sink part of the first method?
- Is there a way to nest operations for each of the workout in the `[HKWorkout]` and call `workoutDetails(_ workout: HKWorkout)` for each one so I get as a result `[WorkoutDetails]`?

What I have attempted so far it's not working.

```swift
HKHealthStore().workouts(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)
    .map({ workouts -> AnyPublisher<[WorkoutDetails], Never> in
        
        return workouts.publisher.flatMap({ workout in
            return Just(workout as! [WorkoutDetails]).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
    }).sink(receiveCompletion: { subs in
        switch subs {
        
        }
    }, receiveValue: { val in
        /// Cannot convert value of type 'AnyPublisher<[WorkoutDetails], Never>' to expected argument type 'Void'
        /// I am not able to get [WorkoutDetails] here as I'd like
        dump(val)
    })
    .store(in: &bag)
```

---

Edit: Solution I've finally used. There are two options that I've finally managed to make it work and understand it.

One is @New Dev's answer to finally receive in the `sink` the combined array and another one is to receive on the `sink` individual elements to save on an array.

```swift
HKHealthStore().workouts(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)
    .flatMap({
        $0.publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }).flatMap({
        $0.workoutWithDetails
    }).sink(receiveCompletion: { comp in
        switch comp {

        case .finished:
            break
        case .failure(let er):
            dump(er)
        }
    }, receiveValue: { details in
        /// Add the individual `WorkoutDetails` elements to an array 
        results.append(details)
    }).store(in: &SGHealthManager.bag)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine framework: how to process each element of array asynchronously before proceeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841254/combine-framework-how-to-process-each-element-of-array-asynchronously-before-pr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach is to `flatMap` the array into a `Sequence` publisher of individual values, then do any async operations on each value (another `flatMap`), then `collect` the results:

```
HKHealthStore()
   .workouts(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)
   .flatMap { workouts in workouts.publisher }
   .flatMap { workout in
       workoutDetails(workout)
   }
   .collect()
   .sink(
      receiveCompletion: { ... },
      receiveValue: { arrayOfWorkoutDetails in
          // arrayOfWorkoutDetails is of type [WorkoutDetails]
      })
   .store(in: &bag)
```

Comment: That's great thanks for the explanation. I've edited my answer with a modification which will push on the sink individual values rather than using `collect` to wait until all the publishers have been processed.

Comment: first flatmap is useless

Comment: @urSus, how so?

Comment: its not sorry, I thought workouts was a array