# Using Combine, how to call multiple api calls on each object in an array?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am calling a function to get a result which is an `AnyPublisher<[Object], Error>`. Now I need to loop through each object and call at least 3 another api calls with the id in a single object.

> AnyPublisher<[Object], Error>
>
> |
>
> Loop though the object array
>
> |
>
> with a property in the object, make 3 api calls(async or sync)
>
> |
>
> with the object and the objects i get from each api call, create
> another object and publish it

How can I do this?

Edit: This is some code that I added to check whether this will work. This is based on the code I found on one of your other posts [Combine framework: how to process each element of array asynchronously before proceeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841254/combine-framework-how-to-process-each-element-of-array-asynchronously-before-pr)
But instead of collecting all the publishers and then coming to map, its going to map after completing the inner flatMap.

What am I doing wrong?

```
struct FoodDetailInput {
    let appear: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>
}

let appearRecord = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()// this is called when the detail page is taken
    let input = FoodDetailInput(appear: appearRecord.eraseToAnyPublisher())

let foodDetails = input.appear
.flatMap({[unowned self] _ in self.dataProvider.ingredients(for: food.id) })
.flatMap({ ingredients -> AnyPublisher<Ingredient, Error> in
    Publishers.Sequence(sequence: ingredients).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
})
.flatMap({[unowned self] singleIngredient  in
    self.dataProvider.variants(for: food.id, ingredientName: singleIngredient.id)
        .flatMap { variants -> AnyPublisher<DetailPageObject, Error> in
            var singleDetailObject = DetailPageObject(ingredient: singleIngredient)
            singleDetailObject.variants = variants
            return Just(singleDetailObject).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .collect()
        .map { detailPageObjects -> PageDetailsState  in
            PageDetailsState.success(detailPageObjects)
        }
})
.replaceError(with:PageDetailsState.success([]))
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing `.flatMap`. Three API calls? You can just chain three `.flatMap` calls — though if you prefer to do them simultaneously you can configure them in an array and use `.flatMap` on that. If you use the former approach, uou will need to keep passing both the object (or the accumulated objects) and the `id` down the chain as you go so that everything you need pops out the end.

Comment: I get an array of food-items. So using the id of each food, I will need to make multiple api calls to create one object which will have some information from the food-item and remaining will be populated using the api calls, for eg: one will give as result the array of items used in it, another will give nutrition information etc.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you could give up your dependency on Combine and use `async/await` instead. But I do really like Combine and I've written an online free book about it: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/

Comment: Can you please check the code I added. I based it on one of your posts but seems like I am doing something wrong @matt

Comment: Even though I never thought like that, thinking from your POV, it surely sounds like I made a demand. Really sorry for that @matt. I have learnt a lot from your posts and comments. Maybe due to that familiarity, I asked like that. I will add a new question and will add the full context for that later.
Like you said, my question's answer is there in your comment and I will approve that.

Comment: Let me know when you've got the new question ready! I really do want to help.